# os not letting me save email attachment using pywin32

Tags: python, email, outlook, pywin32

```
import win32com.client
import pythoncom
import time
import os

class Handler_Class(object):
    def OnNewMailEx(self, receivedItemsIDs):
        # RecrivedItemIDs is a collection of mail IDs separated by a ",".
        # You know, sometimes more than 1 mail is received at the same moment.

        for ID in receivedItemsIDs.split(","):
            print('Running scan...')
            mail = outlook.Session.GetItemFromID(ID)
            email_date = mail.SentOn.strftime("%m-%d-%y" + " at " + "%I:%M:%S %p")
            email_date_stamp = mail.SentOn.strftime('%m-%d-%y_%I:%M:%S-%p')
            email_message = mail.Body
            email_subject = mail.Subject
            email_sender = mail.SenderEmailAddress
            email_attachments = mail.Attachments

            try:

                if check_correct_subject(email_subject) == True:
                        print('From: ' + email_sender)
                        print('Subject: ' + email_subject)
                        print('Date: ' + email_date)

                        if email_attachments.Count > 0:
                            print(str(email_attachments.Count) + ' attachments found.')
                            for i in range(email_attachments.Count):
                                email_attachment = email_attachments.Item(i + 1)

                                report_name = email_date_stamp + '_' + email_attachment.FileName
                                print(report_name)
                                email_attachment.SaveASFile(os.getcwd() + '\\Reports\\Broker_Risk_LDW\\' + report_name)

                                print('Pushing attachment - ' + report_name + ' - to check_correct_email() function.')

                                if check_correct_attachment(email_attachment) == True:
                                    save_incoming_report(email_attachment, report_name, get_report_directory(email_subject))

                                else:
                                    print('Not the attachment we are looking for.')
                                    # add error logging here
                                    break

                        else:  # ***********add error logging here**************
                            print('No attachment found.')


            except:
                pass
```

I am calling the class like this.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    outlook = win32com.client.DispatchWithEvents("Outlook.Application", Handler_Class)

#and then an infinit loop that waits from events.
    pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

The problem here is this line: `email_attachment.SaveASFile(os.getcwd() + '\\Reports\\Broker_Risk_LDW\\' + report_name)`

That folder is already created and it was working before I switched this to a class, in order to work with an Outlook event listener. I am not getting an error message, however the attachment is not saving.

Any tips?

Comment: How do you know it is the os that is the problem?

Comment: I don't - I am just assuming that the issue lies there. Before I made this into an event listener class, I was able to save the file. I'm thinking that it could be something to do with using objects...

Comment: Its just that your title is "os not letting me save..."

Comment: Well that is my assumption.. maybe I am wrong - hopefully you or someone can help.

Comment: What's the purpose of your try/except block?  Are you trying to ignore all errors?

Comment: Yes - I will add error logging later. Because this is a background process, I don't want it to crash - rather would have it report the error that occurred and move on.

Comment: Have you considered that you might be getting an error there and not seeing it?

Comment: Let me test that right now.

Comment: The error I got after testing that: `AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library.Attachment instance at 0x62116912>' object has no attribute 'SaveASFile'`

Comment: I know next to nothing about Python, but it is case sensitive, right? The method's name is 'SaveAsFile' - note lowercase "s".

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too, still getting an error, but a different one. `pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'Cannot save the attachment. File name or directory name is not valid.', None, 0, -2147024773), None)` I've also tried to specify the full path/directory name, but I'm still getting an error

Comment: I got it - the error was in the fact that I was saving the file with colons.